# Symfony2 parallel processing

Tags: php, symfony

I have stumbled into an interesting issue. I'm using Symfony2. The problem simplified is the following. There are two actions and each has a path in routing.yml. The first action does this:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response("first");
```

The second action does this:

```
$start = time();
while(time()-$start < 25);
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response("second");
```

The second action runs a loop for 25 seconds then returns.

I call the second action: domain.com/second(of course it takes time to load), meanwhile I open up another browser window and type in: domain.com/first. This should give me the result in a blink of an eye, however, even the first action waits until the second finishes and they give me the result in the same moment. This happens both in development and production mode. I'm supposing the two processes should run on their own. If instead of the first action, I call a pure PHP script (not Symfony), it returns right away without waiting. Also, if I run the first and the second action in different browsers, I don't have to wait either for the first one to load.

What could cause the problem? The problem stated above is simplified to understand, however, if this was solved, my original, more complex task would work, too.

Thank you for your help: David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (`$_SESSION`) PHP sessions are stored in files. When a connection is made, and `session_start` is called, the users session file is opened and locked.

Therefor, now other connections by the same user/session cant be processed until the session is unlocked.

This may be (not definitely) the case you have run into.

See http://00f.net/2011/01/19/thoughts-on-php-sessions/ and http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/ for a more detailed run through

Comment: Thank you very much! Session was the source of the problem. session_write_close() solved it.